# SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=SEQNAME, DRIVER=4.8.86

Tags: hibernate, jpa, db2

i have exception in my code.
i use frameworks Spring, JPA, Hibernate

maven is:

```
<!-- DB2 Connection -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4_license_cisuz</artifactId>
        <version>10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4_license_cu</artifactId>
        <version>10.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

and to :

```
@Entity
@Table( name="...", schema="..." )
public class Branch {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "O1001ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "O1001NAM")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "O1001COD")
  private String code;

  // getter and setter

}
```

and error is

```
SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=SEQNAME, DRIVER=4.8.86
```

I want to know What is SEQNAME? Did I define it somewhere?

Comment: The error is that when you do WHAT??? You told the JPA provider to perform some operation, but that is a secret. The JPA provider executed some SQL (shown in its log), but that is also a secret. Once you remove the secrecy then people can attempt to answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
logging.file=c:/temp/my-log/app.log

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

in your `application.properties`, this will show you some trace queries.

I had this problem before becouse the JPA is formating your query for example if you are calling `Repository.count();` the query will be formated as `select count(u) From table u` which is in invalid format for the DB2, to overcome this i had to define my own `@Query`to be `select count(*) From table u`.